Malicious BIOS Update Tools
In June on my old refurbished PC, an HP EliteDesk 800 G2 with 16Gb memory and an Intel Core i5-6500T running Windows 10 I bought from MicroCenter, I noticed that I couldn't delete any files to free up memory, alerting me to find out that I had been isolated to a virtual machine within my own computer.  After trying unsuccessfully to reset and then recover multiple times until no longer possible, I decided to buy a brand new PC with Windows 11 thinking it would solve my problems, but that's when the real problem began.
Setting everything up, I went through the install with my same user account and email thinking nothing of it because I left all my old files and programs on the now defunct EliteDesk. Then Windows does the automatic update during the setup, and that's when the malicious root kit file-less firmware malware downloaded from the cloud and onto my brand new PC completely without my knowledge or consent and right past multiple AVGs undetected.
I didn't know about this at first, and only after returning the brand new PC four different times and even exchanging for different brands and builds an additional three times, I figured that my network was compromised  leading to a possible successful user account control attack.
So I canceled my network provider, got a new upgraded one, and installed a Protectli Vault, then went back to get another brand new computer, the one that I'm still having massive problems with, a Asus ROG G16CHR with an Intel i7-1400KF and a 1Tb SSD. I thought everything was secure having configured the Protectli Vault with OPNSense days before setting up the new PC, and so I began hardening and debloating Windows 11 without the internet even connected.
Things were going well at first, but a couple of hours in I heard my Bluetooth speaker randomly beep in my bedroom on the other side of the house which was super sus because I only used it for the TV that I watched there at night. Within milliseconds the brand new monitors on the new PC that I was currently configuring flickered basically at the same time, but I didn't think anything of it until the same process repeated only a few minutes layer. The Bluetooth speaker beeps, followed by the screen flicker again literally within milliseconds!
In horror I realized that they had gotten in through my cell provider to access the Bluetooth to then access my new PC and almost broke my phone in haste trying to get it to power off, but to late and to no avail, because the damage was done. Here's what I speculate happened, please correct me if I'm wrong and I'll appreciate you greatly, because I know nothing and am still learning.
According to Alex Matrosov, founder of Binarly.io and in a post titled "Finding logoFAIL - The Dangers of Image Parsing During System Boot on the same site and as accessed in August 2024, during a massive MSI data breach the Intel Boot Guard Keys for over 166 different products as well as the FW Image Signing Keys for 57 MSI Image Signing Keys were leaked. This gives malicious users zero click remote hacking attack vectors to utilize the Image Parser in Kernel Mode within Verified Boot Trusted Boundaries of UEFI Firmware the ability to hijack the Execution Flow at which point they create a recovery USB to use in a device option to copy the now corrupted BIOS Image file directly into the Firmware Update File to automatically replace the Image file in the unsigned section.
This is directly akin to the UEFI Malware that Forensics Guide Ken Harris talks about in his YouTube channel as accessed in September 2024 called BlackLotus. He explains that it was specifically designed by a certain three letter agency to bypass Secure Boot by accessing the device remotely via hypervisor to access VMs/cloud and utilize the vulnerability to bypass even Windows Defender, BitLocker and even the TPM 2.0 to take over and continue controlling the device.
I've gone to three different PC management and repair professionals who swear each time they've solved the problem believing that Secure Wipe on the BIOS and reformatting the drive allows for a clean recovery and reinstallation of the Windpws 11 OS, but to my understanding of the situation (remember I know absolutely nothing) and to my direct experience this is definitely not the case.
That said, any suggestions for solutions or corrective actions I can utilize at this point? Or do I have to get a whole new CPU and maybe even drive...

We see these kinds of posts from time-to-time here.  Invariably (and this is almost certainly the case here) the problems are nothing like what are described, and the user has not been hacked).    It generally seems like the posters understanding of how IT works is quite warped.  There are lots of signs that the problem is not where/what you think it is, but your post does not give us much to go on to help work out what is going on.

Your new system isn’t and cannot be vulnerable to BlackLotus

Oh yeah? The brand new system I'm currently having problems with is a ROG ASUS G16CHR with an Intel i7-14 gen and an Nvidia RTX 4070S 16 Gb DDR5 and 1Tb SSD that I picked up10/17/24. I also put Pop!OS on a dual boot drive on the EliteDesk after recovery, but it refuses to update because fwupd found affected executables like boot binaries signed with forbidden signatures in the ESP. And yes,  I'm a political and human rights activist and published journalist who happened to start the very first legal cannabis dispensaries in TWO states. Domestic terrorist cause I grow weed, so yeah...

I expect the whole thread will be closed/deleted, so I'm going to take liberties in the answer box - as this won't fit in the comments, and a partial answer/hints is probably of more use to the OP then nothing.
Re your HP EliteDesk 800 G2 - It sounds to me like the problem was drive corruption, and the OS making the drive read-only to stop damage.   The solution to this problem is 2 part - (1) Do a filesystem check/repair and (2) work out why it happened - most likely 2 will be power related or a failing hard drive.   It is almost certainly not related to hacking however.
Re your new PC - "Then Windows does the automatic update during the setup, and that's when the malicious root kit file-less firmware malware downloaded from the cloud and onto my brand new PC completely without my knowledge or consent and right past multiple AVGs undetected." - This is almost certainly false.  Windows updates are signed - so they can only come from Microsoft, and their integrity is assured. - even moreso on a new system.
I point out that evidence your belief above is wrong even goes as far as the inconsistency of your statement.  A new PC won't have multiple AV programs installed at the setup stage.
All the stuff about your network provider is suspect.  Your network provider should be untrusted - and changing network providers should not be your solution.   It is unlikely your provider is attacking you, rather attacks come from the wider Internet through your provider - any provider.    If you are particularly concerned, start by ensuring you have a decent firewall.  (If you are using IPV4 only, most routers do NAT, and this largely protects you from others external to your network compromising your system without you taking some action to reach out to them anyway).
I don't wish to go on debunking the rest of your post - save to say many of the things you rely on are niche/tied to specific hardware/vendors and is likely not applicable to your usage case.  If it was a three-letter-agency or equivalent, they are skilled enough to hide their tracks and don't want to cause you reason to suspect you have been hacked.  These hacks are also pretty expensive (like $500k expensive if done by government agencies)    Are you worth $$$$$$, a diplomat or journalist?
I did want to suggest something you may not have considered
Your incoming power sounds like it may be bad - If thats the case, putting everything behind a UPS would make a massive difference (although you may have additional problems as well)   Why I suspect your power is bad -

Your original system went Read-Only.  A sudden power outage could cause this to occur.
You talk about multiple flickering screens at the same time.   This is most likely due to a power blip.
You talk about lights flashing - these could be systems resetting themselves.

Having your gear on a UPS is a good idea regardless of whether you have been hacked, and certainly something worth considering as a first step.

Good answer, except firewall should be emphasized more strongly.  :)  Even without paranoia of being hacked, firewall is essential.
